# Laravel: Join only if the other Eloquent model exists

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 models, `User` and `Package`. User has many packages and each package belongs to 1 user. I want to retrieve random number of users from database, BUT only if they have packages, something like this:

`return self::orderBy(\DB::raw('RAND()'))->packages()->take(6)->get();`

`packages()` are like simple as this:

`return $this->hasMany($packageModel);`

I have mixed `where('package.name', != ,'')` on the query but that does not work (still returns user that has empty packages). What I want is to take 6 random users THAT have the packages. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Try self::with('packages')->has('packages')->orderBy(\DB::raw('RAND()'))->take(6)->get(); The has method will only return the model with this relation present. PS i havent tested it.

Comment: @MattBurrow: ooh I overlooked `has()` method. Thanks for that~

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by [Matt Burrow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2882596/matt-burrow).*

Use:

```
self::with('packages')->has('packages')->orderBy(\DB::raw('RAND()'))->take(6)->get();
```

The `has` method will only return the model with this relation present.